# Why every single character is interleaved with a null '\00' character using JSON.Net

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

On viewing json file with Hex editor I found that after every single character extra null characters is appended with it, why it is so?
Is there any method by which I can ignore extra null characters because due this I am wasting almost twice as much in IO, file sizes.

Below is the sample hex code that I am getting on opening json file in Hex Editor:

7b 00 22 00 43 00 6c 00 69 00 65 00 6e 00 74 00
54 00 6f 00 6b 00 65 00 6e 00 22 00 3a 00 22 00
5a 00 34 00 47 00 6c 00 5a 00 31 00 4d 00 5a 00
43 00 6c 00 72 00 49 00 6a 00 78 00 41 00 33 00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used a Unicode stream. Make sure you use an UTF-8 one instead.